# Tomcat or Jetty for Java server application

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, architecture, jetty

Suppose I have to design a server to process concurrent completely independent HTTP requests. The processing is mostly CPU-bound (no database is involved).

Requests are relatively small (1-10K) and latency is very important (the less the better). The number of concurrent requests and "rate' (requests per second) are still unknown.

We are going to develop the server in Java. Should we use Tomcat or should we use an embedded HTTP server (e.g. Jetty) as part of the application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either one will satisfy your stated requirements.

Tomcat will require an install - or can be embedded; thanks to Jayan for the correction.  Jetty can be embedded or run in stand-alone mode.  Choose on that basis.

But if you're setting up a centralized server, you might consider Netty over both.  NIO might help your throughput.  Per Joakim Erdfelt below, Jetty uses NIO as well.  Thank you for the education and correction.  I don't know if Tomcat has followed suit.

Comment: Tomcat can be embedded : http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/startup/Embedded.html (I did not check though)

Comment: Jetty does NIO as well.  In fact starting with Jetty 9, all BIO support has been dropped.

Comment: As a bit of an afterthought I wanted to add that your biggest gain here will be in using async servlets in terms of scaling, jetty and I would assume tomcat should not be your biggest bottleneck in terms of performance.